# How to validate a dynamically added input in a form?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, element-ui

I'm adding fields dynamically to my form, but I need these to be validated, as in to make sure they aren't empty. This is how I create my dynamic fields in the form

```
<div v-for="(option, index) in questionOptions" :key="index">
    <el-row>
        <el-col :span="22">
            <el-form-item prop="option">
                <el-input v-model="option.option"></el-input>
            </el-form-item>
        </el-col>
        <el-col :span="2">
            <div class="btn-link-delete action-button" @click="removeOption(index)"
                :disabled="trashDisabled">
                <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
            </div>
        </el-col>
    </el-row>
</div>
```

In my data(), I do this because I want there to be two options there before you can add more fields

```
questionOptions: [
{
    option: ''
},
{
    option: ''
},
```

I want to validate these fields as they are added, right now if I validate the normal way they never get validated correctly, I fill in the inputs and they show as if they are empty and it doesn't let me save, even though the inputs are not empty. I also want the first two fields that appear to be required and validated. Not every item I'm creating will include these dynamically added fields, only some. They are questions and the fields are only if the question is set to be multiple choice, these fields are to create those choices for answering.

Comment: you want to validade this in the laravel controller or in the vue.js file?

Comment: @AlexGuerrero in the vue.js, so that it's not possible to save it if they are empty

Answer (score 0):

If you use [laravel's request class](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests), you can validate all fields there to see if any are empty. 
This is by far the easiest and most robust way to do this.

This will validate your request before it gets to the controller and will allow you to return custom errors.

You'll probably want to store all dynamically added fields in a nested array so you can check that individually.

In the rules section you'd write something like this:

`'dynamic_fields.*' => ['required']`

Hope this helps.

Comment: that doesn't do anything, if anything it gives me errors.

Comment: What specifically doesn't it do and what errors are you getting?

Comment: the syntax is all wrong for the rules, a typical rule goes like `optional: {required: true, message: 'this is required', trigger: 'blur'}` , also I'm not sure what you mean by `dynamic_fields.*`, if I remove the quotes then it all turns red and my page won't run at all, and if I leave it how you have it nothing happens, it's like it isn't even there

Comment: It's not wrong, it's PHP. Did you read my answer or look at the link? This goes on the backend, it's not frontend validation.

Comment: since it said in the rules, I assumed it's the vue, I don't have a rules in my controller

Comment: This is a separate file from your controller. The request will go here before your controller.

Comment: I created the request class, where you say `'dynamic_fields.*'` is that the array that i'm saving them into?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking. So `dynamic_fields` would be an array and then the asterisk tells the request class to validate each item. So `dynamic_fields.* => ['required']` means each field must be filled. From here, you can easily add more rules like data type, IE `string`, `integer` etc.... Here are all the [validation rules](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#available-validation-rules)

Comment: @Nancy, did my answer help? If so, please up-vote and / or mark as the answer.

Comment: I decided not to require those options, because it didn't work any of the ways that I tried, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

i will give you and idea of what i would do

```
methods: {
validate(){
 this.questionOptions.forEach(function(item, key) {      
 if(item.multipleChoice){
   if(item.option===''){
         alert('this question can not be null ' + item.question  )
         return 
      }
   }  
  }
 }
```